# Is there a simple way to plot multiple series on one pandas scatter plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter

I come across this issue constantly; and my current solution is to create additional dataframes, I feel like there must be an easier solution.

Here is an example of data where I have multiple countries with multiple attributes:
[image]

If I wanted to plot Population vs. Depression (%) I would write:

`ax = df.plot.scatter(x='Population', y='Depression (%)')`
[image]

This isn't super helpful, as there are clearly lines linked to specific Countries (df['Country']).  Is there a simple way to plot a scatter plot with different series (colors/shapes/etc) as different Countries?

Right now I use groupby to separate out individual Countries and plot them on the same axes (ax = ax).

Any thoughts or input would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Of course: you `groupby` country and plot the groups in sequence.

Comment: Thanks Prune!  I've used groupby in this case to create new seperate dataframes.  Having n # of dataframes isn't super efficient.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I have no idea.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with this site's purpose.

Comment: Please [include a minimal data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) as part of your MRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try c="Country" and then if you want some nice colors you can go colormap='viridis' for example [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html)

```
ax2 = df.plot.scatter(x='length',
                      y='width',
                      c='species',
                      colormap='viridis')
```

[image]

Since you are using strings as variables we can't use this approach directly and need to convert the data to numbers. This can be done by writing:
`c=df.country.astype("category").cat.codes`

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for the response! This doesn't work, the reason is the value c= needs to be a color.  One possible solution is to make a new column called Colors and then have it be redefined as a different color based on the Country.  This is a lot of work and I'm being lazy! :D

Comment: I just tried it and it works it says in the documentation that it will use a colormap if a column is provided. As seen in example 2 in the documentation :)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, here is the code I'm writing:  ax = df.plot.scatter(x='Population', y='Depression (%)', c='Country')  and here is the error i'm getting: 
 ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not ['Afghanistan' 'Afghanistan' 'Afghanistan' ... 'Global Baseline'
 'Global Baseline' 'Global Baseline']

Comment: Ahh I see the disconnect!  Yes, this works when the column you're specifying as c is a number.  I'm trying to use it as a category, in this case Country.  Best I can figure out is to create unique DataFrames, but i'm sure theres a better solution out there.

Comment: Yes! One workaround would be to use Label Encoding (converting each category to a number) but I think there must be some way to use c on categories

Comment: Okay I found a way and edited my original post :D

Comment: Awesome!  This works perfect for what I need, thank you!!!  I'm going to work a bit on relabeling the color bar to identify the categories.  Thanks again!!!